# How to rename keys in a dictionary and make a dataframe of it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, python-requests

I have a complex situation which I hope to solve and which might profit us all. I collected data from my API, added a pagination and inserted the complete data package in a tuple named `q1` and finally I have made a dictionary named `dict_1`of that tuple which looks like this:

```
dict_1 = {100: {'ID': 100, 'DKSTGFase': None, 'DK': False, 'KM': None, 
'Country: {'Name': GE', 'City': {'Name': 'Berlin'}}, 
'Type': {'Name': '219'}, 'DKObject': {'Name': '8555', 'Object': {'Name': 'Car'}}, 
'Order': {'OrderId': 101, 'CreatedOn': '2018-07-06T16:54:36.783+02:00', 
'ModifiedOn': '2018-07-06T16:54:36.783+02:00', 
'Name': Audi, 'Client': {‘1’ }}, 'DKComponent': {'Name': ‘John’}}, 

{200: {'ID': 200, 'DKSTGFase': None, 'DK': False, ' KM ': None, 
'Country: {'Name': ES', 'City': {'Name': 'Madrid'}}, 'Type': {'Name': '220'}, 
'DKObject': {'Name': '8556', 'Object': {'Name': 'Car'}}, 
'Order': {'OrderId': 102, 'CreatedOn': '2018-07-06T16:54:36.783+02:00', 
'ModifiedOn': '2018-07-06T16:54:36.783+02:00', 
'Name': Mercedes, 'Client': {‘2’ }}, 'DKComponent': {'Name': ‘Sergio’}},
```

Please note that in the above dictionary I have just stated 2 records. The actual dictionary has 1400 records till it reaches `ID 1500`.

**Now I want to 2 things:**

1. I want to change some keys for all the records. key `DK` has to become `DK1`. Key `Name` in Country has to become `Name1` and `Name` in `Object` has to become 'Name2'
2. The second thing I want is to make a dataFrame of the whole bunch of data. My expected outcome is:

[image]

**This is my code:**

```
q1 = response_2.json()
next_link = q1['@odata.nextLink']

q1 = [tuple(q1.values())]

while next_link:
    new_response = requests.get(next_link, headers=headers,  proxies=proxies)
    new_data = new_response.json()
    q1.append(tuple(new_data.values()))
    next_link = new_data.get('@odata.nextLink', None) 

dict_1 = {
  record['ID']: record
  for tup in q1
  for record in tup[2]
}

#print(dict_1)

for x in dict_1.values():
     x['DK1'] = x['DK']
     x['Country']['Name1'] = x['Country']['Name'] 
     x['Object']['Name2'] = x['Object']['Name'] 
    
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_1)
```

When i run this I receive the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "c:\data\FF\Desktop\Python\PythongMySQL\Talky.py", line 57, in <module>
    x['Country']['Name1'] = x['Country']['Name'] 

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: It would be better if you can post the whole traceback, as it will be easy for us to figure out where exactly the problem is.

Comment: @JenilDave I've added the traceback

Comment: Are you able to create a DataFrame using existing dictionary keys as columns? If yes, simply use [pandas.rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) to set desired column names

Comment: @JapunJapun That might be a good idea. However how do I make a df with just the specific keys I mentioned above? Could you show me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working code

```
lists=[]
alldict=[{100: {'ID': 100, 'DKSTGFase': None, 'DK': False, 'KM': None, 
'Country': {'Name': 'GE', 'City': {'Name': 'Berlin'}}, 
'Type': {'Name': '219'}, 'DKObject': {'Name': '8555', 'Object': {'Name': 'Car'}}, 
'Order': {'OrderId': 101, 'CreatedOn': '2018-07-06T16:54:36.783+02:00', 
'ModifiedOn': '2018-07-06T16:54:36.783+02:00', 
'Name': 'Audi', 'Client': {'1' }}, 'DKComponent': {'Name': 'John'}}}]
for eachdict in alldict:
    key=list(eachdict.keys())[0]
    eachdict[key]['DK1']=eachdict[key]['DK']
    del eachdict[key]['DK']

    eachdict[key]['Country']['Name1']=eachdict[key]['Country']['Name']
    del eachdict[key]['Country']['Name']

    eachdict[key]['DKObject']['Object']['Name2']=eachdict[key]['DKObject']['Object']['Name']
    del eachdict[key]['DKObject']['Object']['Name']
    
    lists.append([key, eachdict[key]['DK1'], eachdict[key]['KM'], eachdict[key]['Country']['Name1'], 
    eachdict[key]['Country']['City']['Name'], eachdict[key]['DKObject']['Object']['Name2'], eachdict[key]['Order']['Client']])
pd.DataFrame(lists, columns=[<columnNamesHere>])
```

Output:

```
{100: {'ID': 100,
  'DKSTGFase': None,
  'KM': None,
  'Country': {'City': {'Name': 'Berlin'}, 'Name1': 'GE'},
  'Type': {'Name': '219'},
  'DKObject': {'Name': '8555', 'Object': {'Name2': 'Car'}},
  'Order': {'OrderId': 101,
   'CreatedOn': '2018-07-06T16:54:36.783+02:00',
   'ModifiedOn': '2018-07-06T16:54:36.783+02:00',
   'Name': 'Audi',
   'Client': {'1'}},
  'DKComponent': {'Name': 'John'},
  'DK1': False}}
```

Comment: Thats a first good step but I have 1400+ records. That means I have to do your code 1400 time (1x per ID). You did it just for ID 100. And what about the DataFrame?

Comment: Edited again, just now.

Comment: by the way. You've changed my `dict_1` I  dont have `[]` in my `dict_1`. How did you add them?

Comment: both [] and () are ok, [] is list, () is tuple, dict_1 is tuple right?

Comment: No dict_1 is a dict it starts directly with `{`

Comment: In your case ```alldict=[dict_1,dict_2, ...]```